# Using directives in a component for a route

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

In Angular2 when I am using a router I can specify a component as follows:

```
const routes: Routes = [
   {path:'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent},
   {path:'graph', component: GraphComponent},
   {path:'work', component: WorkComponent}
 ];
```

How would I specify event an event or custom directive in a component.

```
<GraphComponent (bigevent)="handleEvent($event)">
```

When I am using a router it effectively replaces router-outlet with a component. But how do I specify the inputs/outputs for the component that will be called by the router.

Comment: Specifying custom events on a component is typically done with "outputs". Check out [the documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#inputs-outputs) for more on this. But how is that related to the router?

Comment: You can't use bindings with dynamically added components (like the router does). Use a shared service instead https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service